# Axios FormData empty on Server side

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to pass Data from my blade.php via axios (and vue) to my

```
in blade.php
    function() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('a','b')
    axios.post('...', formd:fd);
    }


in Controller.php
    dd($request->all());
```

output of dd:

```
formd:[]
```

works just fine:

```
axios.post('...', vara:"a", varb:"b");
```

So only formdata seems to be the problem..

Answer (score -1):

Managed it:

```
axios.post('...',fd,{headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}});
```